# Recurring Profiles - Ajust Trial Period Amount to Quantity

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, price, paypal, recurring

I have a recurring profile set up for a product with a 2-weeks trial period configured as follows:

- `Trial Billing Period Unit` = 2 weeks
- `Trial Billing Frequency` = 1
- `Maximum Trial Billing Cycles` = 1
- `Trial Billing Amount` = 9$

The product in itself costs 18$. So what I want is that the `Trial Billing Amount` always amounts to 50% of the product price. Eg: if you order 2 of that product, your `Trial Billing Amount` should be 18$ (out of a total price of 36$); if you order 4 of that product, your `Trial Billing Amount` should be 36$, etc.

And yet, it appears that Magento does not adjust the `TBA` according to the ordered quantity. So regardless of the number of products my customers order, their TBA is always 9$.

Would anybody happen to know how to make the `TBA` dependent on product quantity?

Cheers.

PD: I've tried to enter the `TBA` as a percentage (you never know...) but of course it did not work.

Comment: I have done some recent custom work with recurring profiles. What you would need to do is make changes to your payment gateway. I have been using Cryzonic Stripe's modules. I hope this helps.

Comment: i have also same issue on this. I have also used the extension of cryzonic stripe's subscription. Any solution ??